# databricks deployment bicep suddenly failing

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-bicep

The following bicep deployment has suddenly started failing and I do not understand why

```
var managedResourceGroupName = 'rg-metadata-${dataBricksName}'

resource databrickworkspace 'Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces@2018-04-01' = {
  name: dataBrickName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: dataBrickPricingTier
  }
  properties: {
    managedResourceGroupId: managedResourceGroup.id
    parameters: {
      enableNoPublicIp: {
        value: disablePublicIp
      }
    }
  }
}

resource managedResourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: managedResourceGroupName
}
```

This pretty much follows the same doc : [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/workspace/bicep).

The error message I get is

```
The filter 'principalId eq ''' is not supported. Supported filters are either 'atScope()' or 'principalId eq '{value}' or assignedTo('{value}')
```

This error message is quite cyrptic and does not tell me much. Also, this has been succeeding so far. The problem has started now.

Looking at the full doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.databricks/2018-04-01/workspaces?pivots=deployment-language-terraform) , I can see it has things like

[image]

[image]

It says required, but the definition isn't clear as to what do I have to put there. I have never had to use the principalId so far, during the creation of a databricks workspace.

Another fun fact is: the deletion of the resource (databricks workspace which is anyways in a failed state), does not go through and fails too or gets stuck.

Comment: This was working before and you didnt make any changes?

Comment: what is the sku of your data brick ?

Comment: using Premium (+ Role-based access controls) it creates automatically an authorizations block.

Comment: Yes, it worked before, many times as we have multiple existing subscriptions. The sku is premium. I also looked at “view json”  on the resource , on azure portal, which is in failed state, and it did seem to have a principal id set. But when I go to azure ad, I can’t find that principal id. Is this intended? Or is this the problem? Which id should it be? Even the deletion of the resource group fails.

Comment: I left the deletion run overnight yesterday and it did complete finally. When I redeployed everything works as intended again. Point to note is , yesterday, when I looked at the managed resource group (the one created by Databricks internally), I could see an access connector called "access-connector-unity-catalog", which I don't see now. I believe Databricks has been working internally to have the access connector created along with Databricks (and not as a separate resource as now), and that caused problems and they reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a MS Support case for this, as I ended up spending a lot of hours on it. Also, it wasn't something wrong that I was doing- especially because it worked in the past and also, that the same bicep worked flawlessly the next morning.

MS supporthave acknowledged it was a service failure (details below). So, if some of you encounter these cryptic errors and have no idea, what could be going wrong, raise a support case.

```
**Summary of Impact**: 
A few users using Azure Databricks may have experienced failures during Workspace creation with 
Premium Pricing Tier.
 
**Preliminary Root Cause**: 
We determined that a new feature deployed in a dependent backend service, intended to aid 
in the mapping of new workspaces, encountered rate limit issues during the resource provisioning 
process, causing Workspace creation failures as mentioned above.
Mitigation: We performed a rollback of the new feature deployment to a previously known good 
version to mitigate the issue and restore functionality. Additionally, service health has been 
closely monitored to ensure no failures are detected before the issue was declared as fully 
mitigated.Full-service functionality has been confirmed.
```

Answer (score 0):

By referring to the same [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/workspace/bicep) provided by you, I tried deploying databricks with workspace in my environment and was able to deploy it successfully.

```bash
param disablePublicIp bool = false
param workspaceName string = 'newwsj'
param Tier string = 'premium'
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var managedResourceGroupName = 'databricks-rg-${workspaceName}-${uniqueString(workspaceName, resourceGroup().id)}'

resource ws 'Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces@2018-04-01' = {
  name: workspaceName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: Tier
  }
  properties: {
    managedResourceGroupId: managedResourceGroup.id
    parameters: {
      enableNoPublicIp: {
        value: disablePublicIp
      }
    }
  }
}

resource managedResourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: managedResourceGroupName
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

When I open the `JSON` view of the deployed resource, it displays the `provisioningstate` as successful with the specified `principalId`. In addition to the `databricks` account, the above bicep code generates a managed resource group, which includes an `identity` and the `service principal` details. Only at this page, the `service principal` details can be viewed.

***Json view:***

[image]

*Path to view the service principal details:*

```
Managed resource group created for databricks-> Managed identity -> Properties
```

[image]

***And***

Regarding the resource's deletion, it's probably that it's stuck in a failed state, preventing it from being destroyed. You can see if removing the resource group that contains the resource solves the issue.

*Note:* Verify the managed resource group name from the document and provide in your code correctly. Sometimes the variable names also create a conflict for deployment.

*For more information*: Refer [Databricks service principal document](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/service-principals.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20admin%20console%20for%20your%20workspace%20is,the%20Configurations%20tab%2C%20note%20the%20Application%20Id%20value.)

Comment: As per my research there is no correlation between the managed identity principalId and the principalId in the exported template. Can you confirm that the principalId guids are the same ?

Comment: I just mentioned that we can view the identity principal ID details from that path. It doesn't mean that both are same in my view. @Thomas

Comment: I will explore more on this and update it.